# Python 3.4 Make mouse click event advance through a list of data

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, events, tkinter

I have a nested list of data (three dimensional) and I have written a program to give me a generic analysis of the data, and report it graphically.

I would like to work through these graphs with a push of a TKINTER button.

I have assigned the button a `command=NextDataSet` and have a tkinter `tk.mainloop()`. There exists a `graphData()` function that works pretty well.

However, writing `NextDataSet` has turned into a confusing experience.

I have thought about running through each item in the main list, but I want it to stop each time. Hence, I have not put a loop in the command.

```
 def NextDataSet(): 
     for eachDataSet in BigList:
         graphData(eachDataSet)
```

Any thoughts how to display the next dataset in the list, one by one, with a tkinter mouse button event? I have considered passing parameters back and forth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the next dataset can be done with a simple counter.  Note that CamelCaseNames are used for classes.  Functions use all lower_case_with_underscores.  It helps others to read and understand your code.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class CycleThroughClass(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.display_1=tk.Label(master, bg="lightblue")
        self.display_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.display_2=tk.Label(master, bg="lightgreen")
        self.display_2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        tk.Button(master, text="next item", bg="khaki",
                  command=self.next_data_set).grid(row=1,
                  column=0, sticky="nsew")

        tk.Button(master, text="Quit", bg="orange",
                  command=master.quit).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.ctr=0
        self.questions=[["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3],
                        ["four", 4], ["five", 5]]
        self.next_data_set()

    def next_data_set(self):
        if self.ctr < len(self.questions):
            question, number=self.questions[self.ctr]
            self.display_1.config(text=question)
            self.display_2.config(text=str(number))
            self.ctr += 1
        else:
            self.display_1.config(text="Sorry, no more")
            self.display_2.config(text="")


master=tk.Tk()
CT=CycleThroughClass(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: i'm sorry, does a new class have to be created?

Comment: CT=CycleThroughClass(master) creates an instance of the class. One of the many tutorials http://www.freenetpages.co.uk/hp/alan.gauld/tutclass.htm

Comment: I was hoping to understand why you added a new class. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Did you do this because I used CamelCase? I was told this was the best way to name variables, and was unaware that you would interpret it as part of a class.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/213935/why-use-classes-when-programming-a-tkinter-gui-in-python This was helpful